# How to get id in selector field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is this possible to pass the id on selector field? I want where I pass input there pass the id of input is this possible.

```
var $write = $(':input'.get(0)).on('click', function(){     
var yes= this.id;
shift = false,
capslock = false;
var str= Object.values($write);
vivek = str.split (":");        
console.log(vivek);
```

Comment: Is `$('#'+id)` enough?

Comment: Could you try rephrasing your question? it's really hard to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is malformed--there is no closing `}` for the function, or closing `)` for the call to `on`. Also unfortunately, I know English is not your native language and it can be tricky, but we cannot tell what you are asking. What does "pass the id on selector field" mean? What does "selector field" mean? Normally "selector" means something like your `:input`--is that what you mean? If that is the "selector", then what do you mean by "selector field"? What do you mean by "pass id on selector field"? Do you mean "pass **to**"? What would it mean to pass an ID to a selector?

Comment: yes sir i want pass the input id on selector.